# How to execute VS2013 MSBuild from an EXISTING command prompt

Tags: shell, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I would like to "MSBuild" (VS2013) my application as part of a bigger ".cmd" script.  I cannot let visual studio build a shell and issue commands into that shell (please don't ask why; if that were negotiable I wouldn't have to ask this question in the first place)

I have the shell, its path, and its environment variables prepared for everything else (except Visual Studio 2013 and MSBuild).   What can I do or invoke, so that the next command then can be "MSBuild..."

I have spent hours searching in vain but all I have found looks to me like it requires building a new shell, applying a mouse click, or loosing the standard input.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just run vsvars32.bat? It's in `%VS120COMNTOOLS%`.

Comment: My God, this works.  Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

Run vsvars32.bat. It is in the Common7\Tools folder of your Visual Studio installation. In the case of VS 2013, this folder is available in the environment variable, VS120COMNTOOLS. It is similar for other versions of VS. Your script will be something like:

```
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:Build
```